# Location of Airflow Webserver access log

Tags: flask, airflow

I need to access the web access log of Airflow Webserver but I can't find it. I looked at airflow.cfg as well. Does Airflow keep the web access log somewhere? I know it is implemented in Flask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Airflow Webserver access log location is defined in airflow.cfg with default value `access_logfile=/var/log/airflow/gunicorn-access.log`